# Facebook Graph Api Get Event By Id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

I am trying to receive an event from the Facebook Graph Api By Id with following request:

> https://graph.facebook.com/{eventid}?access_token={app_accesstoken}

I am using an app-accesstoken. The Event is a public event and according to the Graph Api docs I should be able to receive public events with any access token: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/

Nevertheless I receive following error-response:

> Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{eventid}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

I have tried with multiple events with the same results

Comment: In the documentation (first link you shared), in the "Reading" section, they list that only an admin of the event can read an event. So they don't explain what the permissions listed above this section are used for

Comment: It say "An access token of an Admin of the Event IF required". As far as I understand this is not required for an open event.

Comment: You are right. It must be an error in the API or the doc is not updated. The solution may be to open a ticket on the fb developer forum

Comment: I've run into the same issue. I can only get public event data for an event I've (the person to whom the access token belongs) interacted with. If I pick a random public event, click "I'm interested in going", then I can get the event data. If I then go back and say I'm not interested in going, then the event gives the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

In April 2018, following the Cambridge Analytics scandal, Facebook decided to greatly reduce the information available through Facebook API.

In particular regarding Events API, here the official statement.

> **Events API**: Until today, people could grant an app permission to get information about events they host or attend, including private
>   events. This made it easy to add Facebook Events to calendar,
>   ticketing or other apps. But Facebook Events have information about
>   other people’s attendance as well as posts on the event wall, so it’s
>   important that we ensure apps use their access appropriately. Starting
>   today, apps using the API will no longer be able to access the guest
>   list or posts on the event wall. And in the future, only apps we
>   approve that agree to strict requirements will be allowed to use the
>   Events API.

After that change you will not be able to get events of Facebook Pages, using the Facebook API like in the old days.

You could be able to get the data of a page you own if you have user_event permission (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/events/) but your app need to pass the App Review process.

Source: https://newsroom.fb.com/news/2018/04/restricting-data-access/